# Relationship Between Span and Linear Dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ be sets of vectors where the cardinality of $I_{1}$ is less than $I_{2}$ and   $\forall e\in I_{2}-I_{1}$ , $I_{1}\cup\left \{e  \right \}$ is linearly dependent. Why would the $span ( {I_{1}\cup I_{2}})\subseteq span(I_{1})$?

Comment: It is enough to prove that $I_1\cup I_2\subset spam(I_1)$. Since already $I_1\subset spam(I_1)$. It is enough to prove that $I_2\subset spam(I_1)$. All elements of $I_2$ are either in $I_1$ or in $I_2-I_1$. Those that are in $I_1$ we already discussed. Those that are in $I_2-I_1$ are being assumed (should be assumed) to be dependent on the elements of $I_1$.

Comment: spam instead of span is cute.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you mean that all the vectors in the difference between $I_2$ and $I_1$ are linearly dependent on each other? Also, I can assume we're drawing the vectors from the space vector space, right?

Comment: @Johnq: I edited the question since then. The vectors are in the vector space.

Comment: For example, the vector space would just be $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ depending how many elements are in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the hypotheses of your claim. Let $w\in span ( {I_{1}\cup I_{2}})$. Then there exists a set of numbers $a_1,a_2,...a_n$ such that $w={a_i}{x_i}$ (where Einstein Summation notation is used, $rank(I_1)=r,rank(I_2)=s,n=r+s, and\;\forall i(x_i\in {I_{1}\cup I_{2}}$). Break the sum up into $w={b_i}{z_i}+{c_j}{u_j}$ where $i\in [1,r]$ and $j\in [1,s]$, so  ${z_i}\in I_1$ and ${u_j}\in I_2$ for all i and j.

Now, note that any vector in the ${u_j}$ part of the sum is either in $I_1$, or it's not. If the first case, then it's part of the $span(I_1)$. If it's in $I_2-I_1$, as it's linearly dependent on the vectors in $I_1$, it to is part of the $span(I_1)$. Therefore as both parts of the sum composition for $w$ (namely the ${u_j}$ and ${z_i}$ sets), are both in the span of $I_1$, if follows that $w \in span(I_1)$ too.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have one question that is still confusing to me. For example, when $u_{j}\notin I_{1} \wedge u_{j}\in I_{2}$ it is dependent, but how do you know that it is in the $ span(I_{1})$?

Comment: Because of the fact that every element in the difference of $I_2-I_1$ is linearly dependent on the elements in $I_1$. That means that there is a linear combination of all the elements in $I_1$ and $u_j$ that don't have all constants zero such that the sum is the zero vector. From there, you can conclude any element in the difference can be represented as a linear combination of the elements in $I_1$ and thus is in it's span.