# Linear Algebra Dependence and Span

Tags: linear-algebra

I posted this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334109/relationship-between-span-and-linear-dependence) awhile ago: Let $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ be sets of vectors where the cardinality of $I_{1}$ is less than $I_{2}$ and   $\forall e\in I_{2}-I_{1}$ , $I_{1}\cup\left \{e  \right \}$ is linearly dependent. Why would the $span ( {I_{1}\cup I_{2}})\subseteq span(I_{1})$?

To answer this question, I was told there is a linear combination for all of the elements of $I_{1}$ that can be represented in the difference of $I_{2}-I_{1}$. How do you know there exists this linear combination?

Comment: Why a new question? Why not just ask this in a comment to the answer of the original question?

Comment: Honestly I have been looking at this question nonstop for about two months and thought I would give it another shot. More times than not leaving comments at the bottom will not be answered. At least the response had a lemma that wasn't fully answered. So I thought I would post it again to see other people's opinions.

Comment: In any case, by $I_2-I_1$, do you mean $I_2 \setminus I_1$ (set difference)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Sorry for the bad argument. So I deleted the answer. As some one has already given a counter example which seems absolutely correct. But i would like to say that statement is true if $I_{1}$ consists of linearly independent vectors only.

Comment: Okay. Why does $I_{1}$ have to be independent?

Comment: I did not write that down, because I did not know it had to be. $I_{1}$ and also $I_{2}$ are both independent.

Comment: @Riju I apologize I did not add that sooner. I know you put all that work into your answer before noticing that. Is there anyway that you could upload  your answer again? I having been looking everywhere for this problem and would truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Riju: I can upload another question too if you would like. I am truly sorry.

Comment: No, you actually didn't get me. I am saying that if you keep your question as it is,  then the $span(I_{1}\cup I_{2})\subset span(I_{1})$ is not true as you an see below in the answer.

Comment: $I_{1}$ should actually be all independent vectors

Comment: But if you have the hypothesis that the vectors in $I_{1}$ are linearly independent then I think the conclusion is true.

Comment: $I_{2}$ should be too and I did not post that in the question.

Comment: The conclusion is true if they are independent and am wanting to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $I_{1}$ is a set of linearly independent vectors.
Let $e\in I_{2}-I_{1}$, then as you have $I_{1}\cup \{\ e \}\ $ is linearly dependent.  Then there exists scalars $c_{i}$'s such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}v_{i} + c_{n+1}e=0$, where $v_{i}$'s are elements of $I_{1}$ and atleast one of $c_{i}\neq 0$. But observe that $c_{n+1}\neq 0$ is necessary since $c_{n+1}=0$, will give a linear dependence of vectors of $I_{1}$, which is a contradiction. So now you can write 
$$e=c_{n+1}^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i}v_{i}$$

And you get the desired linear combination you want.

Comment: I truly appreciate your answer. Can you help me understand why $c_{n+1}\neq 0$? I am just thinking (i.e. $c_{1}=9$ and $c_{2}=-3$ and then $c_{n+1}$ could equal zero and then $v_{1}, ..., v_{n}, e$ would be independent.)

Comment: See atleast one of $c_{i}\neq 0$ right? But if $c_{n+1} =0$, then one of $c_{i}\neq 0$ ($1\leq i\leq n$). Then we will have $\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i}v_{i}=0$ and one of $c_{i}$ is non-zero thus making $ \{\ v_{1}, v_{2},.... ,v_{n} \}\ $ linearly dependent, which is not the case since they are linearly independent.

Comment: That $c_{n+1}\neq 0$ is genius!

Comment: That's what I was missing! I really truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $I_2-I_1$ means $I_2 \setminus I_1$ (set difference), then as stated, it's not necessarily true.

For a counterexample, let $a,b,c,d$ be linearly independent vectors, and let
$$I_1 = \{a,2a\},\;\;\;I_2=\{b,c,d\}$$

On the other hand, if it was stated that the set $I_1$ was linearly independent, then if a vector $e$ is such that the set $I_1 \cup \{e\}$ is linearly dependent, $e$ must be in the span of $I_1$, since you can solve for $e$ in the linear dependence relation.

Comment: I am sorry I did not add that $I_{1}$ had to be linearly independent earlier. I did not think that they were associated that way. I appreciate your answer as well. In fact, it helped make sense what I was missing. Thank you.